# Cannot write to a file within python script, on startup

Tags: python, windows

Basically I have a python script which is "converted" to exe, located in  `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Folder`. When started manually (not as admin), the script can write to file (file is located in the same directory as the script). But when the script runs on startup (I added a registry string to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` with an executable path as data) I get `Permission Denied` error, why is that so and how could I fix it?.   *Code for opening file:*

```
file = open(os.path.join(current_path, "text.txt"), "a+")
```

Error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.\\text.txt'
```

Comment: You misspelled "currnet", but I assume that is not our problem.  I wonder if the "Permission Denied" relates to the exe file or to attempting to write to stdout (assuming your exe does that).  Try redirecting stdin and stdout.

Comment: You have to show the value of `currnet_path`, and the traceback. Don't make people play a guessing game.

Comment: add more details

Comment: Hi, How did you finally solve it? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the script was run from `C:\Windows\System32` not from `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Folder` (windows being weird I guess)